# How to include a php include statment in a php variable?

Tags: php, html

I have a variable including html structure like following:

```
$txt = '<table>
           <tr>
               <td>
              </td>
           </tr>
       </table>';
```

I want to write the following statement inside the variable :

```
include_once('./folder/file.php');
```

I try to write it like the following but it failed:

```
$txt = '<table>
               <tr>
                   <td>';
                   include_once('./folder/file.php');
                  $txt.='</td>
               </tr>
           </table>';
```

And I try it like that and also not work:

```
$txt = '<table>
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                       {include_once('./folder/file.php');}
                     </td>
                   </tr>
               </table>';
```

How can I do that? I am sorry not very expert with mixing php and html so a small help will be appreciated ??

Comment: `include_once` is probably not correct in this case since you're doing templating. Use the non-once variant `include`.

Answer (score 7):

Use Output Buffer functions:

```
ob_start();
include('./folder/file.php');
$include = ob_get_clean();

$txt = '<table>
           <tr>
               <td>' . $include . '</td>
           </tr>
       </table>';
```

See http://php.net/ob

The output buffer gathers everything you'd send to the browser until you empty, delete or end it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

Comment: can you provide a link or something, you might be using it wrong or mix table html elements wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it as follows i believe it is call concatenating:

```
$table_content = include_once('./folder/file.php');
$txt = '<table>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                         ' . $table_content . '
                   </td>
               </tr>
         </table>';
```

or...

```
$txt = '<table>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                         ' . include_once('./folder/file.php') . '
                   </td>
               </tr>
         </table>';
```

To put it simply when I ever need to echo some text out followed by a variable the way I do it is to do as follows:

```
$color = brown
$state = lazy

echo "The quick" . $color . "fox jumped over the" . $state . "dog";
```

This would give the results of:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

For more information see: [Concatenate Strings](http://phphowto.blogspot.co.uk/2006/12/concatenate-strings.html)

Comment: `include` returns false or 1, not the content of the file

Comment: no, my bad, you *can* actually return something from `include`.. interesting (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: This won't work anyways. If you have a file `test.php` include into the variable `$table_content` and you have an `echo "blargh";` in there, it will be printed to the browser, outside of the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$txt = '<table>
           <tr>
               <td>';
$txt.=include_once('./folder/file.php');
$txt.='</td>
           </tr>
       </table>';
print_r($txt);
```