# how can I use $_GET on index.php

Tags: php, get

I have a filed called index.php within the same file I have a function that has links to call other pages as follows

```
function pages() {
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
       switch($_GET['page']) {
        case 'pageName':
             include('pageName.php');
             break;
        default:
             $err_page = include('err_pg.php');
             return $err_page;                             
             break;
    }
} else {
    $default = include('index.php');
    return $default;
}
```

}

But When this function is executed on index.php it shows both pageName as called in index.php?page=pageName as well as index.php at the bottom of pageName. So how can I eliminate index.php to appear immediately after pageName once called?

Comment: Don't include into a variable this way. Either just include and exit/die, or use output buffers - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19115876/1948292

Comment: C'mon Jari, you can do better

Comment: Do you want to open an new page or in same page opens 2 pages? Maybe you need header("Location: pageName.php"); exit(); and not include

Comment: Naa, just improved overall readability, not gonna perform refractoring now.

Answer (score -1):

`die()` instead of `break`ing after including the file.

Comment: `exit` and `die` are aliases.